# Run 'python setup.py test' without running build_ext?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, python-unittest

I try to run `python setup.py test` without running `build_ext` to ensure that any C extensions and project metadata are up-to-date ?

As explain here: 
https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite::

```
python setup.py test
```

first run build_ext and then run unittest.

I have a lot of stuff to compile, and sometime I want to run test without the build_ext (I know that I've not modify compiled thinks)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an environment variable for this. My `setup.py` file checks for the environment variable and sets the `ext_modules` argument to the `setup` function to an empty list if needed:

```
# setup.py

# ...

if os.getenv('NO_BUILD') == 'true':
    extensions = []
else:
    extensions = []

setup(
    # ...
    ext_modules=extensions,
)
```

Then running the test suite with `NO_BUILD=true python setup.py` skips re-building (assuming your shell supports passing environment variables that way).